# Flutter Web signInAnonymously + httpCallable functions = unauthenticated

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, flutter-web

I have written and deployed a `httpCallable` Firebase Cloud Function. I would like to call this function from a Flutter (Web) app.

*Note, I am signed in anonymously via:*

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

My function:

```
exports.callable_proxy = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  ...
}
```

My Flutter code calling the function:

```
final callable = functions.httpsCallable('callable_proxy');
final response = await callable({ ... some data ...});
```

This all works fine when running the function locally in the function emulator. However, the deployed function gives a `unauthenticated` `FirebaseFunctionsException`.

*Note: I have tried adding allAthenticatedUsers role to the Cloud Functions Invoker rules, but that did not make any Difference. Adding allUsers however, works but is not a viable solution.*

*Note: I am able to call the deployed function via HTTP when setting the Auth header with the token of a real user.*

Any ideas how to avoid having to add allUsers role to the function? I dont want this function to be open to the internet.

Thanks.